# What configuration I need in order to connect java with Wamp Server

Tags: java, mysql, wampserver

Based on the title, what must I configure in order to connect to Wamp Server using Java?
I'm having a trouble connecting to the Wamp server.

I have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar` on my `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext`. And also included on my libraries.

This is the database url `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]`

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", " " );

        PreparedStatement executeCommand = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?)");

        executeCommand.setString(1,name);
        executeCommand.executeUpdate();

        return "Success";
    }
    catch ( SQLException err ) {
        return "Failed";
    }
```

Above is my code to connect to my database to test whether it works or not. Everytime I run, it gives me the result `Failed`

Is it something to do with my code problem or my connection to database isn't established?

This is what I get when I run with stack trace. It has more but I didn't copy it

```
SEVERE:   java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
```

Comment: What exactly is your error?

Comment: It doesn't connect to the database. Or is there anything wrong with my code connecting to the database?

Comment: Your code looks OK.  Can you post the exception stacktrace you get?

Comment: What is exception stacktrace? Sorry, I'm a beginner in these kind of things.

Comment: use `catch ( SQLException err ) {    err.printStackTrace();   }` and post the statement

Comment: Just before `return "failed";` insert the statement `err.printStackTrace();` then rerun, copy the stack trace and add it to your post.

Comment: Updated. Please read the question on the `err.printStackTract()`.

Comment: More precise in the statement may be credentials wrong so that use right credentials of the root and try to connect it

Comment: Oh my. I'm such a silly person it is because this line `..."root", " " );` where it should be `..."root", "" );`. I'm so sorry for wasting you guys precious time. Terribly sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove space from password " " to "" and try again

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", " " );
```

Comment: Yea. That is what I did. So sorry for wasting everyone's time here.